# ¿Cómo conservar el formato después de actualizar la tabla dinámica?

Tags: excel, formato, formato-condicional

Estoy teniendo un problema bastante básico pero que no consigo encontrarle solución.
Tengo como 10 tablas dinámicas en una misma hoja, he formateado los encabezados para que la alineación se me quede como se ve en la imagen:
[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo tras actualizar, se me queda desalineada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema surge cuando actualizo las tablas dinámicas, que se reestablece el formato original o por defecto de las celdas y los cambios que he realizado no se me conserva.
Como son tablas que se va actualizando con frecuencia, no puedo estar actualizando y reconfigurando el formato constantemente, por el simple hecho que una vez que entregue el fichero no voy a tener acceso para hacer esto.

He probado a tener marcada la "opciones de tabla dinámica" de "mantener formato de la celda al actualizar", también he probado a desmarcarlo y tampoco, no funciona...es que después de actualizar las tablas, las alineaciones de los encabezados y de la fila del total se me descentralizan.. y los textos vuelven a estar alineados a la izquierda.

También he probado a desbloquear la hoja, configurar el formato y bloquear la hoja pero tengo el inconveniente de tener que bloquear la hoja para poder actualizarlo, por lo tanto para actualizarlo tengo que desbloquear la hoja y volvemos a estar en la misma.

He probado a rehacer alguna tablas para probar a ver si el problema es de la hoja de calculo en cuestión y no funciona tampoco.

¿Os ha pasado algo parecido? ¿Alguna recomendación que podéis indicar por favor?

Comment: Es un problema común. Yo lo llevo sufriendo muchos años y no hay solución rápida. Aquí "capean" el problema editando el formato predefinido de la tabla dinámica. Dale un vistazo por si te sirve: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/pivot-table-formatting-after-refresh/m-p/2561411/highlight/true#M107255

Aquí otro ejemplo: https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-format.html

Comment: Me temo que es el comportamiento nativo de las tablas dinámicas. Dices que ya tienes tus 10 tablas con sus encabezados formateados. Siempre puedes hacer una macro que actualice los datos y vuelva a aplicar el formato que quieres a tus encabezados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, el enlace pasado arroja algo de información y es genial saber que no soy la única que está sufriendo con esto. @dogwall

Answer (score 0):

en opciones de tabla dinamica en diseño y formato sacar ticket a mantener ancho columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]